# Using PCA trained on a large data set for a smaller data set

Tags: machine-learning, pca

Can I use a pca subspace trained on, say, eight features and one thousand time points to evaluate a single reading? That is, if I keep, say, the top six components, my transformation matrix will be 8x6 and using this to transform test data that is the same size as the training data would give me an 6x1000 vector.

But what if I want to look for anomalies at each time point independently? That is, can rather than use an 8x1000 test set, can I use 1000 separate transformation on 8x1 dimensional test vectors and get the same result? This vector will get transformed into the exact same spot as if it were the first row in a much larger data matrix, but the distance of that one vector from the principal axis doesn't appear to be meaningful. When I perform this same procedure on the truncated reference data, this distance isn't zero either, only the sum of all distances over the entire reference data set is zero. So if I can't show that the reference data is not "anomalous", how can I use this on test data?

Is it the case that the size of the data "object" used to train pca is the size of object that can be evaluated with it?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: I don't see how you can look for anomaly in a single sample, anomaly is a behavior you compare to some non-anomalous behavior, but if you have a single sample, you don't have anything to compare to. Besides, doing PCA on a single sample is quite meaningless. You will get a single PCA direction (the direction of the sample) and a single non-zero eigenvalue. So you didn't learn anything new - the subspace will be just the sample itself.

Comment: Yes, the "single sample" question was meant to gauge the limit of very small sample sizes, but generally, is it the case that PCs trained on data with X samples can only be used to evaluate data with X samples? In all cases we're talking about a covariance matrix of the same size, it's just a matter of how much data is used to calculate the covariances. In principle, for perfectly periodic data, once period should be enough to accurately represent samples of any length, right? Is there a general rule for how many samples you can evaluate on test data given a size of the training data?

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'evaluate'. You can always learn (that is, calculate the covariance matrix) on N samples, and then apply (that is, project along the PCs) a single sample. But I don't think that is what you mean. Also, if you assume something on the statistics of the data, for example that it comes from a linear subspace of small dimension plus some noise, then there are a lot of theoretical results regarding the error of evaluating the covariance matrix from a finite sample.